# How to access (declare/assign value to/get value of) a variable by a String?

Tags: java, class, variable-expansion

How may I specify a name by using a String in Java?

```
String VARIABLE = "name";

Something VARIABLE = new Something();
```

Is there any posssible way I can do something like this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Specify a name for what? The variable type?

Comment: Basically I want to name a variable using the value of a String.

Comment: you just can't do that

Comment: You probably have a misguided way of thinking about your problem if this is what you need to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I want to name a variable using the value of a String.

You can't do that. Names of variables need to be know at compilation-time to let compiler do its work, not at run-time. What is more, after compilation variables doesn't have names.

If you are searching for something like `key->value` mapping where key can be dynamically created String, and instance of `Something` will be values you can use `Map<String,Something>`.

Example:

```
Map<String,Something> map = new HashMap<>();
//lets put our pair in map 
map.put("name", new Something());
//lets print value stored in `name` key
System.out.println(map.get("name"));
```